# Why do you need to add permission to open/run a file from terminal in linux?(chmod)

Tags: linux, chmod

I want to open a PDF file from terminal so i used xdg-open  and then it showed {File type Zip archive (application/zip) is not supported} so i looked up on google then it said to use chmod to add permissions and use xdg-open and i did it and it worked but why do i need to use chmod command before?

Comment: It seems that your pdf file is actually a zip file. Try  unzipping it first.

Comment: i checked it,but it seems thats not the case